# Parsing HTML table using Python 3 and beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So I have HTML tables where I have parsed the data and I have it printing out in the console.

HTML Code:

```
<table class='hdr'><tbody>
<tr><td class='hdr_name'><b>Station ID: </b></td><td class='hdr_value'><b>TUA1-W03281</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class='hdr_name'><b>Serial Number: </b></td><td class='hdr_value'><b>C737201011071281   Nest Number : RFID = N1111003 TS = N0000001</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class='hdr_name'><b>Date: </b></td><td class='hdr_value'><b>Wednesday, July 04, 2018</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class='hdr_name'><b>Time: </b></td><td class='hdr_value'><b>9:26:25 AM</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class='hdr_name'><b>Operator: </b></td><td class='hdr_value'><b>No operator logged in</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class='hdr_name'><b>Execution Time: </b></td><td class='hdr_value'><b>118.3051362 seconds</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class='hdr_name'><b>Number of Results: </b></td><td class='hdr_value'><b>169</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class='hdr_name'><b>UUT Result: </b></td><td class='hdr_value'><b><span style="color:#008000;">Passed</span></b></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

My Code to scrape the data:

```
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

testURL = open('Report - C737201011071281 - 04-07-18-92626 AM.128144458.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(testURL, "html.parser")

'Station ID'
station = soup.find("td", text="Station ID: ").find_next_sibling("td").text
print("\nStation ID:    " + station)

'Serial Number'
serialNumber = soup.find("td", text="Serial Number: ").find_next_sibling("td").text
cNumber = serialNumber[0:15]
print("Serial Number:    " + cNumber)

'Date'
date = soup.find("td", text="Date: ").find_next_sibling("td").text
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%A, %B %d, %Y')
print("Date:    " + datetime_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

'Time'
time = soup.find("td", text="Time: ").find_next_sibling("td").text
time_object = datetime.strptime(time, '%I:%M:%S AM')
print("Time:    " + time_object.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

'Result'
result = soup.find("td", text="UUT Result: ").find_next_sibling("td").text
print("UUT Result:    " + result)
```

Later on in the HTML the table used had no class or id, and what I want to do is to be able to go through each row until I find a row that has the word "Focus" in it. When this row is found, I want to go through each row underneath that row, until I reach the row that has the word "Result" in it.

Below is the HTML as to how the table is created:

```
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Focus:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centre_Score:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0.08565902709961</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Top_Left_Score:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0.06830544769764</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Top_Right_Score:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0.06978666782379</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bottom_Right_Score:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0.06947886943817</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bottom_Left_Score:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0.07671363651752</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Result:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>1</span></td></tr>
```

How do you iterate over each row after the row that has the text "Focus: " and store the values of each parameter in an array called "Focus Results".
I am new to Python and would appreciate any feedback especially on the .py script I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to do something like this:
You first search for the "Focus:" and then iterate over the siblings of its parent (other rows). You get the results you need in the res dictionary.

```
all_labels = soup.find_all("td", class_="label")
res={}
for label in all_labels:
    if 'Focus' in label.text:
        for sib in label.parent.next_siblings:
            if isinstance(sib, Tag):
                lab = sib.find('td', class_='label').text.strip()
                val = sib.find('td', class_='value').text.strip()
                res[lab] = val
                if 'Result' in lab: break
        break;
print res
```

Comment: But what value do u want to return if there is none? What is the results you are looking for from parsing this HTML part?

Comment: What if you have two row's that are both just labels i.e 'Focus_Threshold' & 'Centre_Threshold'. 'Centre_Threshold' is a sub paramter of Focus so I would like to include it in my output like below.

Focus_Threshold: {'Centre_Threshold: ' 'min val', 'max val', 'Corner_Threshold: ',  'min val', 'max val'

`<tr><td class='label' >Focus_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' >Centre_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' >Minimum:</td>
<td class='value' '>0</td></tr>

<tr><td class='label' >Maximum:</td>
<td class='value''>0</td></tr>
`

Comment: How is this part related to the previous one? Is the Focus Threshold between 'Focus' and 'Result'?

Comment: I have a row called "Focus Threshold" and a row underneath called "Centre Threshold". Both have no "value" class.

The "Focus" basically has two params called "Centre" and "Corner" and they have params called "Max","Min".

What I would like to do is print it out like so:
Focus_Threshold: {'Centre_Threshold: ' 'min val', 'max val', 'Corner_Threshold: ', 'min val', 'max val'

So I need to look for the "value" class and return the value from "Max" & "Min" from both the "Centre" & "Corner" Thresholds

Comment: I got that, but is this problem within the previous question. In the sense, are 'Focus Threshold'  and 'Centre Threshold' between the 'Focus' and 'Result' rows? Or it is unrelated with the previous part of html.

Comment: I will post a new question because I think this problem is a bit different. I will try to explain better in that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to achieve the expected output:

```
for items in soup.find_all("td"):
    if "Focus" in items.text:
        data = items.find_parent("tr")
        for elem in data.find_next_siblings():
            if "Result" in elem.find(class_="label").text:break
            item = elem.find(class_="label").get_text(strip=True)
            value = elem.find(class_="value").get_text(strip=True)
            print(f'{item} {value}')
```

Output:

```
Centre_Score: 0.08565902709961
Top_Left_Score: 0.06830544769764
Top_Right_Score: 0.06978666782379
Bottom_Right_Score: 0.06947886943817
Bottom_Left_Score: 0.07671363651752
```